# Running rostests with bag data

Tags: rosbag, jenkins, rostest, gtest, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the processing of standing up some regression tests, and my tests require that I can play back bag data against my node, and then monitor the output. `rostest` conveniently provides all the tools I need to complete this, but what's considered best practice for where the bag data should be stored? I can't have my tests failing on Jenkins because the bags are missing, but then I also don't want my repo to get unreasonably large, and I will have quite a few of these regression tests to run. Should I just run them offline?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192986/running-rostests-with-bag-data/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the test data is small it is usually ok to put them into the repo beside the tests. In cases where the test data is bigger I would recommend to place them in a publically fetchable location.

E.g. the tests for rosbag itself are fetching several bag files for verifying that the behavior has no regressions. See https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/8ea90cb30bb29e073234fd8de8063c3e1adc94d9/test/test_rosbag/CMakeLists.txt#L18

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-09-18**:
Great, thank you!